# C# list issue in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, list

I have been working on a wcf application and have been trying to return a list of names from an sql server database. My main issue is that my select * statement only returns the last value of the list. Here is the code.

Name Model:

```
public Name GetName()
    {

        Name name = new Name();

        using (SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Names", sql))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                name.NameID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                name.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
```

.svc:

```
public Name GetNames()
    {

        Name serviceName = new Name();
        NamesModel model = new NamesModel();
        Name modelName = model.GetName();
        serviceName.NameID = modelName.NameID;
        serviceName.Name = modelName.Name;

        model.Close();

        return serviceName;
    }
```

NameService:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getnames")]
    Name GetNames();
```

I have tried to print the value out to a list but there seems to be a disconnect somewhere. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The solution is definitely to put it in a list. What do you mean by "I have tried to print the value out to a list but there seems to be a disconnect somewhere."?

Comment: what do you mean by disconnect? is there some kind of exception? if so, please provide its message and other details

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NameServices.Entities.Name>' to 'NameServices.Entities.Name'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but the code shown definitevely doesn't return any list....
I try to guess your intentions and suggest to change in this way ....

```
   public List<Name> GetNames() 
   { 

        List<Name> names = new List<Name>(); 

        using (SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Names", sql)) 
        { 
            SqlDataReader reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            while (reader.Read()) 
            { 
                Name name = new Name();
                name.NameID = reader.GetInt32(0); 
                name.Name = reader["Name"].ToString(); 
                names.Add(name);
            } 
        } 
        return names; 
    }
```

.svc:

```
    public List<Name> GetNames() 
    { 

        NamesModel model = new NamesModel(); 
        List<Name> names = model.GetNames(); 
        // ?? serviceName.NameID = modelName.NameID;  
        // ?? serviceName.Name = modelName.Name; 

        model.Close(); 

        return names; 
    }
```

NameService:

```
[OperationContract] 
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getnames")] 
    List<Name> GetNames();
```

Comment: Excellent, that sorted it! The main issue I was having was resolved with the "List<Name> names = model.GetNames();" line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only get one name because you only fill one name. You need to fill a List in your while loop and return that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Model:

```
public List<Name> GetNames()
{

    List<Name> names = new List<Name>();

    using (SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Names", sql))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Name name = new Name();
            name.NameID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            name.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            names.Add(name);
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

.Svc

```
public List<Name> GetNames()
{

    NamesModel model = new NamesModel();
    List<Name> serviceNames = model.GetNames();

    model.Close();

    return serviceNames;
}
```

NameService

```
[OperationContract] 
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getnames")] 
List<Name> GetNames();
```

Comment: I have tried that but I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NameServices.Entities.Name>' to 'NameServices.Entities.Name'.

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more explicit for the entire code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was the line "List<Name> serviceNames = model.GetNames();" which solved the issues of using a list.